# MySQL Using a trigger to update quantity on another table if part is used

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, insert

I am new to triggers but want to know how I can use one in my database.
I have created a table for a maintenance log, a parts inventory, and a parts_used junction table. When maintenance is carried out the parts and log id's a inserted into parts_used. I want to be able to take subtract 1 from the quantity in the inventory for that part.

**Maintenance log**

```
CREATE TABLE maintenance_log (
    idlog int  (4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idVehicle int (2),
    description VARCHAR (80),
    entry_date DATE(),
    release_date DATE,
    idMechanic int (2),
    FOREIGN KEY (idVehicle) REFERENCES vehicles(idVehicle),
    FOREIGN KEY (idMechanic) REFERENCES mechanics(idMechanic),
PRIMARY KEY (idlog)
);
```

**Parts**

```
    CREATE TABLE parts (
    idParts int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    part_description VARCHAR (60),
    quantity int (2),
PRIMARY KEY (idParts)
);
```

**parts_used**

```
CREATE TABLE parts_used(
    idParts int (3),
    idlog int  (4),
CONSTRAINT PK_partUsed PRIMARY KEY
    (
        idParts,
        idlog
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (idParts) REFERENCES parts(idParts),
    FOREIGN KEY (idlog) REFERENCES maintenance_log (idlog)
);
```

My current trigger just returns ERROR with no other message. This is what I am using.

```
CREATE TRIGGER subtract_quantity
AFTER INSERT ON parts_used FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
           UPDATE parts
           SET parts.quantity = parts.quantity - 1
           WHERE parts.idParts = NEW.idParts
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Can anybody help or offer any advice?

Comment: It looks like you have two accounts based on the account that tried to edit the question. You can [request the accounts to be merged](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to fix it.

Comment: Check the permissions granted to the _executor_ of the trigger.  In particular, can he write to `parts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `DELIMITER` directives *both* before *and* after the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, you need to end individual simple statements with semicolons, and you need to end the complete `CREATE TRIGGER` with the delimiter specified in the first `DELIMITER` directive:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER subtract_quantity
AFTER INSERT ON parts_used FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE parts
    SET parts.quantity = parts.quantity - 1
    WHERE parts.idParts = NEW.idParts;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

However, in this case your entire trigger body is a single `UPDATE` statement, so you can omit both the `BEGIN ... END` statements and the `DELIMITER` directives:

```
CREATE TRIGGER subtract_quantity
AFTER INSERT ON parts_used FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE parts
    SET parts.quantity = parts.quantity - 1
    WHERE parts.idParts = NEW.idParts;
```

(The `DELIMITER` directives allow the parser to distinguish between the end of a compound-statement trigger or procedure body and the ends of the individual simple statements it contains, and are only required by some MySQL clients.)

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! I was confused by the use of delimiters but this is helpful. Thanks again